# Persons who successfully placed tokens on public exchange: did you shared source code of contract?

Tags: exchanges

One of my clients created token (standard ERC20) and want to put it to public exchange site. Exchange policy requires reference to Github repository. Client asking whether it safe to share source code of contract (it could contains some code that they treating as "something sensitive" and kinda "our invention") and afraid that it is not safe and somebody could create competitor using they codebase.

Could you please share your experience - would you provided source codes of smart contract that contained something more complex then ordinary ERC20-compliant logic?

Comment: Consider it from this point of view, properly written solidity code is the only thing that protects your users money (ETH). So if you don't make the code publicly available, there's no way of proving that you haven't made mistakes that others could exploit, or even intentionally put exploits in to take advantage of them yourself.

Comment: I wouldn't provide the source code if this code is worth a lot of money. Of course hackers can exploit your code without sources if you have a bug, but if you don't feel giving away the code then don't. You can create your own exchange through Ether and that's it. The only think exchange does for you is a marketing task, so you can implement the same logic that exchange has, and market it on your own. No need to give away code. I would give away code if this would benefit the company in some way, like create free advertisement, etc...